# react native search filter, open modal with search and list to select

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to make an apps like the picture below

- the first image showing the first state,
- the second image showing a modal with a search and the list, after you touch "Pilih"
- the third image showing the final state, after you choose the list from the second image

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkEWg.jpg)
[open modal with search and list to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxaKT.jpg)
[the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJM2F.jpg)

Does anyone know what I need to use (Textinput/Modal/ListView/TouchOpacity etc) in order to make an app like the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a pretty straightforward structure.

First, you will have your first screen with nested View component and Text component. In the second row of "Ke Rekening", you will have it TouchableOpacity that when you touch, will present a Modal component.

Second, in that Modal component, you will have a TouchableOpacity component for your button, Textinput component for your search, and FlatList component for your list. In that FlatList, it will consist of TouchableOpacity component that when you press, it will pass the information and dismiss the modal to the first screen again.

Third, in that first screen, you can display your selection in there.

Let me know if there is something that is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will try to implement it tomorrow.

Comment: i've done it with touchableopacity and the flatlist. now i'm making the search function

Comment: That is good. Search function is basically just filtering your data through the typed text and then applied the filteredArray to your FlatList